# What could be the cause of short flickering of screens

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, displayport, 4k-resolution

I have assembled a new computer lately and bought two new screens.

The screens (two 4K Asus PB279Q) are each connected to the video card (EVGA GeForce 980Ti) by Display Port. In order to reach 60 Hertz, I have set the display and video card to use Display Port 1.2 mode and 60 Hertz.

Now I notice that around 1-3 times per day the screens flicker. The flickering is looking like an image loss, but it is not on the whole screen. It starts like from the top and goes down within a few milliseconds. After that, everything is back to normal and can stay like that for hours.

As I am working quite a lot on the machine, the problem still should be solved. What can it be? Video card, driver, cable or display? Anything else?

Video card: I cannot say anything about it except that changing the slots didn't help (I have 3 DP slots and 2 displays).

Displays: Both screens have the problem.

Cable: I used the cables which were delivered with the displays.

Driver: Always updated to the newest driver, on Windows 10.

What would you do? Where to start looking?

Comment: What software was running , or full screen software ?  or whatever your doing during these times? Do you have any stong interferance items around you can test for , like a cell phone that is doing a far bounce to do a cell tower connect (even when in standby)?  a router that sits right next to the wiring, or other possibles like a microwave on your computer desk :-0  right after it occurs, see if any item arrives in  the event log, for the display adapter.

Comment: @Psycogeek: I only noticed it on Desktop use (not gaming), probably because I am mostly working. Indeed I always place my cell phone close to me (=the screens), but I have the feeling it should flicker more then? There is a Wi-Fi device (Sonos Play5) close to me, that's all besides the phone. I'll continue my search...

Comment: @Psycogeek I am using a premium cable now on display 1 and I still have the issues. Video card, displays or interference it is then...

Comment: I do not know, it kind of sounds like a sync problem , but with it only occuring a few times a day, and only very quick not many people would worry about it. you do know about the 59 - 60 refresh rate thing, as that is an odd one that MS did to use a (sort of) drop frame sync at 59.9? is the actual rates, so they started displaying it that way , how that could effect it?  only if your forcing something (that wanted to be at the other).  Like here on one monitor is was always picking 59 for me, and I wanted 60 , well it isnt "really" 60 to get technical. anyways you could try that if it exists

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar problem but with two different computers (Win10 desktop running GTX 970 w/ DisplayPort and Surface Book w/ Mini DisplayPort, both directly connected and through dock). Also running DisplayPort 1.2 @ 60hz. Roughly 1-4 times a day half of screen becomes distorted for a split second. Occasionally full screen black flicker. Seems to be monitor issue since it happens on 2 diff computers w/ diff cables. No obvious source of interference.

Comment: @ChadLevy with the same screen model as I mentioned?

Comment: @andreas yes, ASUS PB279Q 27" 4k

Comment: @ChadLevy in a German forum, they were saying that many 4K screen panels made by AUO for Acer, Asus and others have this issue. The manufacturers simply dont seem to care about the customers and are quiet about it... If the problem is really disturbing you, you can get a full refund by Asus after sending the screens in twice. Obviously, the replacement screens will have the same problems - I also had them replaced...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this problem can really just be the panel in the screens.

In the meantime, I found out that people owning 4K Acer and Asus screens have the same problem. Manufacturers seem to ignore the flickering and hope the customers will not notice it at all.

Asus will refund the full price of your device after sending the screen in for at least 3 times. If you own a screen that has the flickering problem, you might consider this option.

There is no fix available.

Answer (score 0):

I my case it was a problem with heatsink on the main PCB. It was touching chip only on one side with a mm gap on another filled with paste. Another smaller heatsink was also fitted badly. After refitting heatsink no more flikering